# Google Charts: ChartRangeFilter and CategoryFilter with discontinuous DataTable

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Charts to display multiple curves in a `LineChart` with two controls: `CategoryFilter` and `ChartRangeFilter`.

I want `ChartRangeFilter` to display only selected columns in `CategoryFilter`, but I often get exceptions:

> One or more participants failed to draw()

and/or

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd[0].x')

I think the problem is that the data I need to show are discontinuous, here's an example:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'DATE');
data.addColumn('number', 'DATA.1');
data.addColumn('number', 'DATA.2');
data.addColumn('number', 'DATA.3');
data.addRows
([
    [new Date(2016,9,19), 18,   null, null],
    [new Date(2016,9,20), 24,   null, null],
    [new Date(2016,9,21), 41,   null, null],
    [new Date(2016,9,22), 47,   null, null],
    [new Date(2016,9,23), 60,   null, null],
    [new Date(2016,9,24), 79,   null, null],
    [new Date(2016,9,25), null, 3,    null],
    [new Date(2016,9,26), null, 4,    null],
    [new Date(2016,9,27), null, 10,   null],
    [new Date(2016,9,28), null, 11,   123],
    [new Date(2016,9,29), null, 4,    130],
    [new Date(2016,9,30), 6,    null, 132],
]);
```

and a code snippet of my chart:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <title>NEW CHART</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
  .labels{font-size: 50%;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cal/formatDate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------GOOGLE CHARTS ->
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart ()
  {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('date', 'DATE');
   data.addColumn('number', 'DATA.1');data.addColumn('number', 'DATA.2');data.addColumn('number', 'DATA.3');
   data.addRows
   ([
    [new Date(2016,9,19),18,null,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,20),24,null,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,21),41,null,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,22),47,null,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,23),60,null,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,24),79,null,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,25),null,3,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,26),null,4,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,27),null,10,null],
    [new Date(2016,9,28),null,11,123],
    [new Date(2016,9,29),null,4,130],
    [new Date(2016,9,30),6,null,132],
   ]);

   var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

   var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
   columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
   var initState= {selectedValues: []};
   // populate columnsTable Rows skipping column 0
   for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++)
   {
    columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
    // comment out next line to have a default selection other than the whole list
    // initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
   }
   // set individual columns to be the default columns (not with the loop above)
   // initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(4));
   
   // initialize the CategoryFilter
   var CategoryFilter_control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper
   ({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'CategoryFilter_div',
    dataTable: columnsTable,
    options: 
    {
     filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
     ui:
     {
      label: 'Columns',
      allowTyping: false,
      allowMultiple: true,
      allowNone: false,
      selectedValuesLayout: 'aside'
     }
    },
    'state': {'selectedValues': ['DATA.1']}
   });
   
   // initialize the LineChart 
   var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper
   ({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options:
    {
     title: 'SOCIAL FOLLOWERS',
     curveType: 'function',
     interpolateNulls: 'true',
     pointSize: 2,
     legend: { position: 'right', textStyle:{ fontSize: 10 } },
     chartArea: { left: 50, top: 10, width: "80%", height: "90%" },
     trendlines:
     {
      0:
      {
       type: 'linear',
       lineWidth: 1,
       dataOpacity: 0.2,
       showR2: false,
       pointSize: 0,
       visibleInLegend: false
      },
      1:
      {
       type: 'linear',
       lineWidth: 1,
       dataOpacity: 0.2,
       showR2: false,
       pointSize: 0,
       visibleInLegend: false
      },
      2:
      {
       type: 'linear',
       lineWidth: 1,
       dataOpacity: 0.2,
       showR2: false,
       pointSize: 0,
       visibleInLegend: false
      },
     }
    }
   });

   // initialize the ChartRangeFilter
   var ChartRangeFilter_control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper
   ({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'ChartRangeFilter_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options:
    {
     filterColumnIndex: 0,
     ui: { chartOptions: {height:50,width:'100%',chartArea:{left:50,width: '80%'}} }
    }
   });

   // set the chart
   function setChartView ()
   {
    var state = CategoryFilter_control.getState();
    var row;
    var view = {columns: [0]};
    for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++)
    {
     row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
     view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
    }
    chart.setView(view);
    chart.draw();
   }

   // set the ChartRangeFilter ??
   function setRangeFilterView ()
   {
    var state = CategoryFilter_control.getState();
    var row;
    var view = {columns: [0]};
    for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++)
    {
     row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
     view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
    }
    ChartRangeFilter_control.setView(view);
    ChartRangeFilter_control.draw();
   }

   // display selected Range
   function displayRange()
   {
    var v = ChartRangeFilter_control.getState();
    document.getElementById('dbgchart').innerHTML = v.range.start.format("%d-%m-%Y")+ ' to ' +v.range.end.format("%d-%m-%Y");
    return 0;
   }

   // draw the CategoryFilter
   CategoryFilter_control.draw();
   // bind LineChart and ChartRangeFilter
   dash.bind([ChartRangeFilter_control], [chart]);
   
   dash.draw(data);
   setChartView();
   setRangeFilterView();

   google.visualization.events.addListener(CategoryFilter_control, 'statechange', setChartView);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(CategoryFilter_control, 'statechange', setRangeFilterView);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(ChartRangeFilter_control, 'statechange', displayRange);
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------GOOGLE CHARTS <-
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Social Followers Overview</h3>
 <div id="dashboard">
  <div id="CategoryFilter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div" style="margin:0; padding:0; width: auto; height: 75vh"></div>
  <div id="ChartRangeFilter_div"></div>
  <p><span id='dbgchart' style="padding-top: 50; padding-left: 50px;"></span></p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to prevent trying to draw `null` data when there are *holes* in the `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround here
[How to remove default error message in google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898925/how-to-remove-default-error-message-in-google-chart)

so I added this code to `drawChart()` function:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function (googleError) {
    google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
});
google.visualization.events.addListener(dash, 'error', function (googleError) {
    google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
});
```

but if you move the thumbs to select a range where some data are missing, the error occurs (even if it is removed) and the chart won't change...